# App crashes as soon as i press one of the buttons

Tags: android, android-studio

```
    import android.os.CountDownTimer;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    TextView timer;
    TextView score;
    CountDownTimer test;
    int sum = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btn_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Start);
        Button btn_2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tapper);
        btn_1.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_2.setOnClickListener(this);
        timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);
        test = new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                timer.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                timer.setText("done");
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        if(v.getId() == R.id.btn_Start){
            test.start();
        }else if(v.getId() == R.id.tapper){
            sum++;
            score.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
        }
    }


}
```

I'm trying to create an app where you can press a button while a timer is counting down, I haven't gotten very far as far as functionality goes, but I have stumbled upon one problem. When I launch my app and press either of the buttons, the app crashes and I'm not sure why. I'm pretty new to Android Studios, sorry if the question is bad.

Thanks for answering.

Comment: post the stack trace in your question.

Comment: In the logcat Monitor, are there any exceptions being thrown? I would be willing to bet there is some uncaught exception being thrown causing the app to crash

Comment: the variable "score" is never assigned to anything, hence its null and probably causes the crash.

Comment: @snixtho You are correct, sir!